# Xamarin Android - CrossGeeks - AzurePushNotificationPlugin - Hide Notifications if app is in foreground (android and ios)

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, notifications, push

I'm using CrossGeeks AzurePushNotificationPlugin

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/AzurePushNotificationPlugin/issues/40

How can I achieve notifications are not displayed if app is in the **foreground** on android/ios?

Only the event OnNotificationReceived or another event should be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the silent key to the data payload      .

```
        "data":
        {    
            "title": "Testtitel",
            "body" : "Notification Hub test notification2",
            "silent" : "true"
        }
```